# Cannot cast String to ClassName

Tags: java, android

While I can do the following

```
int a =10;
long b = (long)a;
```

I am wonder why I am getting exception while trying following,

```
Test test = new Test();
String s = test.toString();
Test test1 = (Test)s;
```

Any clarifications would be more helpful.

Comment: how could it be a String and Test object at the same time ?

Comment: You don't need to cast in the first case: `long b = a;`. This is just a widening conversion, which is defined in the language spec.

Comment: Read about boxing and unboxing for the first two lines

Comment: What exactly is the point? All you need is `Test test = new Test(); Test test1 = test;`.

Comment: Casting is not object conversion. You seem to have a basic misunderstanding here.

Comment: Why do you think you can? Are you trying to use `toString` as a serialization method?

Comment: 'Somewhere else, not at the same time' is meaningless. You need to explain yourself properly. But `toString()` is conversion; type-casting is not.

Comment: Kindly stop calling me 'bro'. I am not your brother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting doesn't actually make a new object. You are trying to say to the compiler:

> You think this is a reference to a type `String`; but trust me, I know it's a type `Test`.

It doesn't actually change the object in any way.

But if the reference is to an instance of `String`, it can't possibly also be a reference to an instance of `Test`, so the compiler forbids the cast: `Test` is not a subclass of `String`.

To convert a `String` to a `Test`, you actually need to construct an instance of `Test`. For instance, there may be a constructor which takes a `String`; then:

```
Test test1 = new Test1(s);
```

or maybe there's a static factory method:

```
Test test1 = Test1.buildFromString(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Test` is not type of `String` and cannot be casted. toString() is a method that converted one to another. 
What you probably need is a Test constructor that takes String and builds objects based on provided data.